# Emacs Support for Typescript

Tags: typescript, emacs

"How do I get Emacs to syntax highlight Typescript?"

I'll start with the apology. I have tried and tried. Emacs 24 on Ubuntu Virtualbox VM.  Please help me!  package-refresh-contents just sits there with "Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80"

(I.e. I've never managed to package-refresh-contents to work ever.)

I've managed to configure Emacs Neotree sidebar, all sorts of customizations but nope, this one's got me stumped.
I know it sounds like "hold my hand" with this one. But please, could someone just take me through it baby step by baby step.

"How do I get Emacs to syntax highlight Typescript?"

Please excuse any etiquette shortcomings as this is my first post ever. (gives an idea how frustrated I am) aaarggghhh!!!

Comment: If you type `M-x eww`, starting the built-in web browser, and try to visit some web pages, what happens? Does that also get stuck? Also, are other programs in your VM able to access the internet?

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Everything works in all other applications.  Wow!  :) never knew about M-x eww. works fine.   But still just hangs there with "Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several package for work with Typescript, from simple syntax highlihting in `typescript.el` to development environment implemented in `tide`, and some other.  The emacswiki [lists all of them](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/TypeScript). But you'll need [to setup MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/getting-started) to use them.

P.S. Regarding the VM - check that the regular browser in VM can access internet, and recheck network settings of VM - I've seen when VirtualBox, for example, had conflict with Windows HyperV.

Comment: HELP!! I've looked at the link you provided. my system does not contain either of the files that are described there. init.el and package.el. I would like to do some actual programming at some stage. This is ridiculous. I don't suppose emacs would let the world know where this package.el file is located. I suppose after googling the www while doing a system wide search on my machine should come up with something. But alas can only locate /usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/emacs-lisp/package.el.gz and
/usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/emacs-lisp/package.elc. Can you explain what I need to do please?

Comment: The other link just tells me that there are a bunch of wonderful typescript support packages that anyone who knows how to write the emacs application code from scratch might be able configure with very little effort. (assuming they have whatever other files that they will most likely need). Any prospect of being able to let anyone know how to install them?

Comment: Sorry for the failing etiquette but I am frustrated beyond belief at why this has to be so difficult?

Comment: your init file should contain call to `package-initialize` - you can execute it via M-x as well.  After that you can simply execute M-x package-install, and select package to install

Comment: Thanks Alex. I executed M-x package install and now I get "install package:" prompting me in the minibuffer. So, what do I do now?? Thanks, please stay with me on this. Cheers

Comment: you need to type the name of the package in minibufer, like, 'typescript', and press ENTER.  You can use TAB to complete name based on partial match.  You can press TAB twice to show alternatives

Comment: I can start building Angular apps now!

Comment: You can to upvote my answer, and accept it as answer... Right now you accepted your own answer

Answer (score 1):

If the main obstacle is installing the package from the package list, you can bypass that step by visting the ELPA page in a web browser, downloading the tar file for the package, and installing it with `M-x package-install-file`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Alex Ott takes the honors. Looks like all I had to do was type 
m-x install-packages and then when prompted with "install-package:" type typescr [tab] to get a list of possible completions which contained one called typescript. hit enter and Voila! .ts files highlight syntax!!!

I don't seem to understand where this package lives or anything but, who cares? It works!!

Thanks to all (esp. Alex)